# Reading dynamic header from csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csvreader

I am working on an application where I send requests to get API which returns CSV with a large set of data. I need to read the list of data from CSV but the data headers are not consistent though they are the same their row number can be changed. I am trying to get the list of data from **YEAR, MO, DY, HR, ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN, CLRSKY_SFC_SW_DWN**. The column headers will be the same always. I want to dynamically map the list of records to my **DTO** for that I have implemented the code but always gives me an error for example **YEAR[0]** doesn't exist.

```
public class ResponseDTO
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Hour { get; set; }
        public decimal ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN { get; set; }
        public decimal CLRSKY_SFC_SW_DWN { get; set; }

    }

    public sealed class ResponseDTOMap : ClassMap<ResponseDTO>
    {
        public ResponseDTOMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Year).Name(("YEAR"));
            Map(m => m.Month).Name("MO");
            Map(m => m.Day).Name("DY");
            Map(m => m.Hour).Name("HR");
            Map(m => m.ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN).Name("ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN");
            Map(m => m.CLRSKY_SFC_SW_DWN).Name("CLRSKY_SFC_SW_DWN");
        }
    }




 public async Task<IEnumerable<ResponseDTO>> GetDataAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await GetStreamAsync(url)))
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<ResponseDTOMap>();
                    var records = csvReader.GetRecords<ResponseDTO>().ToList();
                    return records;

                }
            }

        }
```

Here is the image of the CSV file.
I need to read the data below the highlighted area.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code with the project/solution please?

Comment: This is main implementation

Comment: try add reader.ReadLine(); for 10 times after you construt the stream reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as below to make the pointer on the right place

```
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    reader.ReadLine();
                    // it was not used to read text but adjust  the position of pointer, in your case,you need add the codes for 10 times 
                    reader.ReadLine();
                    reader.ReadLine();
                    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                    {
                        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<TestModel>().ToList();
                    }
    
                    
                }
```

Result:
[image]

also,open your csv file as below and check if the  name contains sapce,it may also cause the error you've shown
Correct:
[image]
Wrong:
[image]